# Git repo hosted on Bitbucket.. Count each day where I pushed a commit

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'd like to estimate how much I worked on a project.
I'd like to count each day where I made a commit.
So I'll know how many days I did any work at all on this project.

Bitbucket doesnt seem to have info like that available in its web-app (unlike github)

But can you get this sort of info using git commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `git log` for that:

```
git log --pretty=tformat:%ad --date=short | sort -u | wc -l
```

`git log` will take every commit from the current branch (alternatively, you can specify the name of the branch), print its "author date" in short form (e.g. `2018-09-15`), then `sort -u` will remove duplicates, and `wc -l` will count the number of lines.

This assumes you are the only person to commit to that repo. If that's not the case, use filters to limit the commit list, for example:

```
git log --author='me@example\.org' ...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from="2019-10-07 00:00:01"
to="2019-10-07 23:59:59"
users=$(git shortlog -sn --no-merges --since="$from" --before="$to" | awk '{printf "%s %s\n", $2, $3}')
IFS=$'\n'
echo -e "User name;Files changed;Lines added;Lines deleted;Total lines (delta);Add./Del. ratio (1:n);Commit count"

for userName in $users
do
     result=$(git log --author="$userName" --no-merges --shortstat  --since="$from" --before="$to" | grep -E "fil(e|es) changed" | awk '{files+=$1; inserted+=$4; deleted+=$6; delta+=$4-$6; ratio=deleted/inserted} END {printf "%s;%s;%s;%s;%s", files, inserted, deleted, delta, ratio }' -)
     countCommits=$(git shortlog -sn --no-merges  --since="$from" --before="$to" --author="$userName" | awk '{print $1}')
     if [[ ${result} != ';;;;' ]]
     then
        echo -e "$userName;$result;$countCommits"
     fi
done
```

Use above script to get more details